# Best Practice for Updating Listeners after Ajax Load

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the best way of updating my Javascript event listeners after I load new content onto the page? I realized my click listener wasn't working if I added it before I loaded data into my feed. To fix this problem I put it in the .done callback of my ajax call.

```
$(".likebutton").click(function(){
    //function
});
```

If I load more data into the same feed the click listener gets added again to all the instances of .likebutton that were there before. This means sometimes my function gets called 2 or even 3 times depending on how many times I've loaded new data.

I know I can remove a listener on all objects and then add a new one each time, but I'm not sure if that's the best practice.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Supposing that you always load the new content inside a specific element, like a div with id `content`, you could use the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to delegate the click event to this element.

```
$('#content').on('click', '.likebutton', function() {
    // your code
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nxpgp/ (note that every new `.likebutton` will respond to the click event)

Comment: WOW! I've never seen this done anywhere before. Very good trick Guilherme. I think I'll be using this.